# Limit text field size in product custom attribute to 80 characters

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, adminhtml, product-attribute

I have just created a custom attribute (standard text field) on a simple product. I'd like to limit this field to 80 characters as it's to be used as an eBay title to integrate with eBay.

I only want to limit this field though, not all text fields.

Can someone advise how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge Magento does not allow the limiting of lengths for EAV attributes. For a varchar this gets stored in the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` which has the definition `value => varchar(255)`.

One option you could do is to add a backend model for this attribute. In this model you could write your own `beforeSave` function that will process the length of given value and trim it to be the desired length. The class should extend `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract`

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    if ($object->hasData($attrCode)) {
        $object->setData($attrCode, substr($object->getData($attrCode),0,50));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid any custom editing for each attribute, there is a module that builds this into Magento for you. It allows you to have a Limit or a Minimum number of Characters for any attribute. All editable at the "Edit Product Attribute" screen in Magento:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/attribute-character-limit.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$string = $product->getData($attribute_code);

echo substr($string, 0, 80);
```